# Adding a second developer on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm having an issue adding a collaborator on an App Engine project.

The collaborator gets an email from App Engine, clicks the link, and is presented with an *accept* button. Pressing *accept* seems to do nothing, and the collaborator is still listed as "pending" in App Engine's permissions.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? It sounds like something that may have just been a temporary glitch.  Otherwise I'd wonder how old your collaborator's browser was and if they had JavaScript disabled.

Comment: An idea: is your collaborator using multiple Google accounts? Ask him/her to try to logout from all Google accounts before clicking the link---might have to copy/paste the link if she reads the e-mail in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the person you are inviting is logged in under the proper Google Account. Sometimes you can end up logged into your personal Gmail when your browser hits the *Accept* URL, even though you clicked the link from a different email address (for instance, a Google Apps address for a new employee).